# C++ pure virtual method implementation by other class

Tags: c++, derived-class, pure-virtual

Lets look at class **A** that comes from external library

```
class A {
    public:
        void method() {
            cout << "hi";
        }
};
```

and my abstract class **B** with pure virtual `method()`

```
class B {
    public:
        virtual void method() = 0;
};
```

i have created class **D** derived by **A** and **B**

```
class D : public A, public B {

};
```

But when I create an instance of **D**, I get following error:

`error: cannot declare variable ‘d’ to be of abstract type ‘D’`

How implement class **D** it was not an abstract class and could call `method()` from class **A**?

Sample code: http://ideone.com/yxGWvM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must override `method`in `D`. You can do it like this

```
class D : public A, public B {
public:
    void method() override {
        A::method();
    }
};
```

Comment: `override` is C++11 only. It is good to use it if supported/allowed, but also works without.

Comment: It's 2014 here... ;-)

Comment: Choose it for best answer cause `override`

Answer (score 2):

Define the function in `D` and use the implementation provided by `A`.

```
class D : public A, public B {
public:
    void method() {
        A::method();
    }
};
```

Comment: @Warthel4578: This is definitely the right way to do it. When using C++11 you may add `override`. As the downvoters did not leave a comment I assume they are from the common stackoverflow haters...

Answer (score 1):

```
class B {
    public:
        virtual void method() = 0;
};
```

B has pure virtual function, any class (D) derived from that class (B) *must* override to create instance of class.

So D should be,

```
class D : public A, public B {

    void method() 
    {
       //implementation 
    }
//other code

};
```

Comment: @Warthel4578 What you define in A is different method. If you want to call that method from D, you should use A::method()

Answer (score 1):

A class derived from an abstract base class will also be abstract unless you override each pure virtual function in the derived class.